# <ul> sub item count issue

Tags: jquery, html

Below is the code will be generated dynamically (between `<li> </li>`) and  removed.

```
<div class="popup-content">
    <ul id="ulpopup" class="share-items-list">
        <li>
            <div class="item-container"> 
                <a href="#" class="close"></a>
                <span class="icon icon-kind-file icon-kind-pdf">PDF</span>
                <span class="item-title">Notes from the last meeting</span>  
                <a href="#" class="link-icon link-secondary icon-info-sign icon-medium"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="item-container"> 
                <a href="#" class="close"></a>
                <span class="icon icon-kind-file icon-kind-doc">DOC</span>
                <span class="item-title">Legal and 401k info</span>  
                <a href="#" class="link-icon link-secondary icon-info-sign icon-medium"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Following is the jQuery to remove the item.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();

    var count1 = $('#ulpopup > li:visible').length; // way 1

    var count2 = $("#ulpopup").children().length; // way 2

    var ulId = document.getElementById("ulpopup"); // way 3
    var count3 = ulId.children.length;

    alert(count1);
});
```

whenever i add / delete the items the count are not pulling the updated count.

please helpme out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$(this).parent().remove();` to `$(this).parents('li').remove();` to remove the list item containing the close button

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
        $(this).parents('li').first().remove();

        var count1 = $('#ulpopup > li').length; // way 1

        alert(count1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent of `close` is the `item-container` element, you need to remove the `li` containing the clicked `close` element.

For that you can use the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

You need

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();

    var count1 = $('#ulpopup > li').length;

    alert(count1);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TBzXm/)

Answer (score 0):

`.close` is your `<a>`

So `$(this).parent()` is your `<div>`

So `$(this).parent().remove();` just remove the div, not the `LI` you're counting

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ul>

alert( "Size: " + $("li").size() );
alert( "Size: " + $("li").length );
```